# how to bypass certificate error in opera browser with python selenium on browserstack?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

When testing on opera browser with python selenium on browserstack I see the following certificate error
[image: certificate error]

How can I bypass this with python selenium? I have tried adding the capability
`desired_cap['acceptSslCerts']=True` but that doesn't work.

Comment: As Opera 20 uses the Windows certificate store, the warning can be bypassed.
If you want to use a unknown selfsigned certificate, you have to add it to Windows Trusted Root Certificates (But be careful using certificates without proofing they are really for the server!).

Comment: thanks for the help but adding to trusted certificates is not possible..I am using browserstack and I am looking particularly for a solution with python selenium

Answer (score 1):

As per the link, https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities, I believe the correct way of setting 'acceptSslCerts' capability is('**t**rue' and not '**T**rue'):

```
'acceptSslCerts' : 'true'
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Opera 20 and above uses the Windows certificate store, the warning can be bypassed.
If you want to use a unknown selfsigned certificate, you have to add it to Windows Trusted Root Certificates (But be careful using certificates without proofing they are really for the server!).

See: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows